# How to generate the Test case report in selenium Webdriver using Junit

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver

Good Morning,
I am using Java as a language and Scripted the entire code in selenium junit.
I scripted the Code through selenium Web-driver mechanism.
Now ,The scripting is come to an end but i am not aware of the best way to generate the Test case report.
Further I need to implement the entire process on server,So Please suggest the best way to generate the Test Case status report.

Answer (score 5):

**Allure** is the Framework that u are looking for

It supports different Unit testing frameworks across different languages including ***JUnit4***....moreover it integrates easily with different projects since there are lot of adapters readily available. Here is their site....

[Allure Documentation](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki)

Do check their demo Reports before integrating

[Allure Demo Reports](http://teamcity.qatools.ru/repository/download/allure_core_master_release/lastSuccessful/index.html?guest=1#/home)

Answer (score 0):

With JUNIT I have used [UnitTH](http://junitth.sourceforge.net/) which has very good mechanism for generating Historical reports in JUNIT. I sets up neatly with ANT.

There are different types of graphs and Bar Charts for displaying the reports as below: [image]

Every Suite run is shown in a Grid on main page using which you can navigate to any particular suite run  in the past for details:

[image]

enter image description here

Sample suite run:[image]

There is also a Jenkins Plugin if you wish to use. It's open source and freely available, let me know if you face any difficulties integrating it in your project.